# Git pull in application. Without using batch file. LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#, git, console-application, git-pull, libgit2sharp

I want to git pull when my apllication start in folder. After that I take all dlls from this directory.

> C:\TESTS\front-tests

I do not know how to implement this problem, so sorry that I do not have code. I asking for simple code of pull request.

Comment: Googling "C# git" gives a coupe of good hits, do you have problems with any of those solutions?

Comment: I asking only for sample code which I can modify to my needs. I have no idea how to start with LibGit2Sharp.

Answer (score 2):

From you're question, it looks like you're after the `repo.Network.Pull()` method from LibGit2Sharp.

Basically, Pull automatically performs a Fetch (retrieving the new commits from the upstream repository) and a Merge. As such, the method accepts a `PullOptions` optional parameter which allows one to tweak the process (see **[PullOptions](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/PullOptions.cs)**, **[FetchOptions](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/FetchOptions.cs)** and **[MergeOptions](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/MergeOptions.cs)**).

In order to get started, one may take a look at the Pull() unit tests in **[NetworkFixture.cs](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/NetworkFixture.cs#L133-L197)**.